# How do I Restrict internet Access for Some Sites?

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

I configured my server to work as a DHCP. My question is how can I restrict Some sites' access for other users like blocking youtube, blocking social media, and other sites and allow only some limited sites?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details and maybe examples to make it more clear how your network is set up and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DENY rule from LAN to WAN in your firewall and set the PC ip address as the source. Use a DHCP reservation or static IP address to make sure the PC keeps the same address.

Or - set the IE proxy to a fake/null IP address (127.0.0.1 for example)

Or - remove the default gateway details from the PC (will prevent routing over any LAN to LAN vpns though),  you can check more about proxy server from this post, i found this [post](https://monovm.com/blog/what-is-a-proxy-server/) on Internet, hope this will help you.